# Java program on name Initials

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program that will give the Initials of the name(String) user gives as input.
I want to use the `Space function` while writing the name as the basis of the algorithm.
For eg:

```
<Firstname><space><Lastname>
```

taking the char once in a for loop and checking if there is a space in between, if there is it will print the charecter that was just before.
Can someone tell me how to implement this?
I'm trying this but getting one error.

Any help is dearly appreaciated..
P.S- i am new to java and finding it a lot intresting. Sorry if there is a big blunder in the coding

```
public class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = new String();
        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You entered : " + name);
        String temp = new String(name.toUpperCase());

        System.out.println(temp);

        char c = name.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(c);

        for (int i = 1; i < name.length(); i++) {
            char c = name.charAt(i);

            if (c == '') {
                System.out.println(name.charAt(i - 1));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Ok Finally got it. The algorithm is a lot fuzzy but its working and will try to do it next time with Substring..

```
for (int i = 1; i < temp.length(); i++) {
    char c1 = temp.charAt(i);

    if (c1 == ' ') {
        System.out.print(temp.charAt(i + 1));
        System.out.print(".");
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: Could you describe what error you're getting?

Comment: The program is not compiling the error is 
if(c == '') -- Over here its not taking '' as a valid syntax

Comment: if you want to test for a space you should write `c == ' '`

Comment: Please format your code accordingly before posting

Comment: Sure, am new here so dont know much about the posting rules 
Will do surely from next time 
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do something like this:
Remember, you only need the inicial characters

```
public staticvoid main (String[] args){
   String name;
   System.out.println("Enter your complete name");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   name = input.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Your name is: "+name);
   name=" "+name;
   //spacebar before string starts to check the initials
   String ini; 
   // we use ini to return the output
   for (int i=0; i<name.length(); i++){
      // sorry about the 3x&&, dont remember the use of trim, but you
      // can check " your name complete" if " y"==true y is what you want
      if (name.charAt(i)==" " && i+1 < name.length() && name.charAt(i+1)!=" "){
         //if i+1==name.length() you will have an indexboundofexception
         //add the initials
         ini+=name.charAt(i+1);
      }
   }
   //after getting "ync" => return "YNC"
   return ini.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((^| )[A-Za-z])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Some Persons Name");
    String initials = "";
    while (m.find()) {
        initials += m.group().trim();
    }
    System.out.println(initials.toUpperCase());
}
```

**Output:**

```
run:
SPN
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great solution.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a regex:

1. keep only characters that are following a whitespace
2. remove all remaining whitespace and finally
3. make it upper case:

`" Foo Bar moo ".replaceAll("([^\\s])[^\\s]+", "$1").replaceAll("\\s", "").toUpperCase();`

=> `FBM`

Comment: this slight maj works when punct between names  :"John-Doe".replaceAll("([^\\s|^\\p{Punct}])[^\\s|\\p{Punct}]+", "$1").replaceAll("\\s|\\p{Punct}", "").toUpperCase();
res59: String = JD

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance (will run this method many times), the extra charAt(i+1) isn't needed and is relatively costly.
Also, **it'll break on texts with double spaces**, and **will crash on names that end with a space**.

This is a safer and faster version:

```
public String getInitials(String name) {
        StringBuilder initials = new StringBuilder();
        boolean addNext = true;
        if (name != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
                char c = name.charAt(i);
                if (c == ' ' || c == '-' || c == '.') {
                    addNext = true;
                } else if (addNext) {
                    initials.append(c);
                    addNext = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return initials.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getInitials() {
          String initials="";
          String[] parts = getFullName().split(" ");
          char initial;
          for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
              initial=parts[i].charAt(0);
              initials+=initial;                  
           }      
          return(initials.toUpperCase());
 }
```